# Question on Terminology used in the Teaching of the Ari regarding Levels within the Highest Emanation

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah

In Otzrot Hayyim, Sha'ar Tant"a (Ta'amim Nekudot Tagin Otiyot), in a description of Adam Kadmon, the first form taken by the line of light of the Infinite that enters the vacated space, it says that there are four aspects to the internal being of Adam Kadmon, refered to as 72/Av, 63/Sag, 45/Mah, and 52/Ban, or as Ta'amim, Nekudot, Tagin, Otiyot. It seems that each of the four is again divided into four sub-divisions to make 16 aspects. These are not fleshed out. But in the case of the one level (Sag/Nekudot) that is described in further detail, it is a sub-division into three that is described, with the three aspects referred to as ta'amim elyonim, emtsa'iyim, and tahtonim, i.e, the cantillation marks in a text of the Bible that have their place above the line, those that have their place in the middle of a line, and those that have their place below the line. Why the sub-division into three rather than four, when it seemed like the principle was that the structure would sub-divide into components that mirrored the whole? If there's no room for a fourth level in the representation based on the types of ta'amei ha-mikra then why is that representation used?

Comment: Some dejargonizing is in order here, as is some background information. What is the subject of this (other than Kabbalah)? Four levels of what? What do the abbreviations stand for? That's for starters.

Comment: @SethJ This might be one of those questions where if you don't get it already, you aren't likely to be helpful in finding the answer or likely to be ever searching for the answer later.

Comment: @doubleaa, I totally would have agreed with you before the edit. I had no idea what he was asking about. Now, though, I still don't have an answer, but I feel competent enough to make further changes to improve the question (and I'm sorely tempted to do so).

Comment: Seth J, please go ahead and edit if you want or let me know what to do to improve the question and I'll try to edit.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have expertise in this area, but the following is my understanding of the topic as discussed in אוצרות חיים:

First of all, the [*n'kudos*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niqqud) we use naturally fit into three categories based on their placement. Likewise for the [ta'amim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantillation), the middle ones are identified [as follows](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31261&st=&pgnum=5):

> הטעמים האמצעיים שבאמצע התיבה והם פס״ק ומק״ף כנודע

This seems to refer to the *munach l'garmeih* (as well as the *shalsheles*) and the *sof pasuk* (where the word carries a *makaf*), respectively. In both cases the words are followed by symbols that are neither above nor below the letters, unlike all other *ta'amim*.

After reading the section more carefully, it seems that the three divisions (upper, middle, and lower) of ע"ב and ס"ג are unrelated to what you call "the four sub-divisions" of each of the four expansions of HaShem's name. The three divisions of both ע"ב and ס"ג are mechanisms for filtering the Divine light, corresponding to figurative body parts of Adam Kadmon. The three divisions of ע"ב correspond to the *ta'amim*. At this level, the Divine light is so sublime that it is [impossible to discuss it or even conceive of it](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=31261&st=&pgnum=4).

Therefore, R' Chaim Vital begins with a discussion of the three elements of the filtering process of the Divine light at the level of ס"ג, corresponding to the three categories of *ta'amim* (even though overall it corresponds to the *n'kudos*) as well as the figurative ears, nose, and mouth of Adam Kadmon. R' Chaim Vital describes how the light is filtered through these elements and becomes progressively less intangible.

The comparison of the ס"ג expansion to the categorization of the *ta'amim* into upper, middle, and lower, is a means of characterizing the filtration of the light at that level. The fact that there are three categories seems to be incidental. By contrast, R' Chaim Vital mentions that each of the four expansions of HaShem's name contain elements of all four. The four aspects contained in each of the four expansions are ways of referring to different incarnations of the light at different levels, as opposed to the means by which the light is filtered.

Comment: Thanks, Fred. Just to note, I meant the division of Ta'amim, though you're right to note that for Nekudot the threefold division holds true too and it would be the same problem. In regard to: ההבל היוצא מן הראש דרך נקבי השערות I understood that as being Av/Ta'amim at the macro level, so it doesn't explain the absence of a fourth sub-division _within_ the level Sag/Nekudot.

Comment: Shalshelet, like munach legarmeh, has a pseudo-psik following it as well. (Disclaimer: I don't know if that is relevant vis-a-vis the Kabbalah discussion. I can only comment about the trop.)

Comment: Fred, I mean that when this topic of ta'amim elyonim, emtsa'iyim, and tahtonim comes up, the text is talking specifically about the level of Sag, the second highest level. The comment that you quoted was specifically about Av, the highest level. –

Comment: @paquda You're correct. I've rewritten the answer.

Comment: Thank you, Fred, interesting answer, but note that the division into 3 types of ta'amim is, confusingly, not a division of the level of ta'amim (av) but of the level of nekudot (sag).

Comment: Maybe that implies another level of sub-division: 4 x 4 x 3? so that what's being referred to is a division into 3 of the ta'amim level of the nekudot level of the whole. My question would then still be why division into 3 instead of 4.

Comment: @paquda I edited in your point about the ta'amim. The division into 4x4 is necessary because it refers to each of the 4 expansions including elements from all of them. I don't see why *everything* has to be in fours. (Interestingly, though, if you read on a bit you'll see that the three levels are further subdivided).